# Show/hide a DIV with javascript fails - dialogbox locked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have this ASPX:

```
<div id="IsAccountingOk" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Luk" class="close">X</a><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsAccountingOkHeader" runat="server" Text="Kassekladde:" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Der skal først vælges regnskabsår!"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnIsAccountingOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnIsAccountingOK_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

My intention is to show the DIV as a dialogbox - but the dialogbox is totally locked and I can't acccess the elements inside it and the closebutton too. Furthermore is it possible to access the rest of the controls in the background - which not should be accessed.

I think I have to deal with the 'pointer-events' selector - but I don't know how to do it :-(

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Michael

**(I have updated my CSS in according to the opacity style selector.)**

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong style property of the element, you should set the `opacity` to show the element:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('IsAccountingOk').style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;1
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    --color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IsAccountingOk" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Luk" class="close">X</a><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsAccountingOkHeader" runat="server" Text="Kassekladde:" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Der skal først vælges regnskabsår!"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnIsAccountingOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnIsAccountingOK_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MichaelEriksen, looking at your CSS, it seems you have set the `opacity` property not `display`, please check the updated answer:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at it - but in the meantime I can see that I cant get the ClientID. So I think that I have to take a look at this issue first.

Comment: @MichaelEriksen, initially I thought the id with the element is created by ASP, but it is not, you have to use `ClientID` only for the server generated controls like `lblIsAccountingOkHeader`, `lblMessage` and `btnIsAccountingOK`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have now got the dialogbox to be shown with the opacity selector. But the dialogbox is locked and the background is unlocked! Any ideas howto fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide or show functions in jQuery.
or if you want to set animate , use fadeOut (hide) or fadeIn(show).

first , you have to hide element . so :

Example for hiding element :

```
$('#exampleID').hide();
```

or

```
$('#exampleID').fadeOut();
```

if you want show element use this :

Example for showing element :

```
$('#exampleID').show();
```

or

```
$('#exampleID').fadeIn();
```

Notice : use jQuery 3xx . replace your element's ID with exampleID.